# Display attributes from item in drop down menu in excel form

Tags: forms, excel, vba

Could someone help me with this?  I'm relatively new to excel and the VBA environment.  What I need to do is create a form with a drop down menu that selects a certain key.  Lets say I have the following two spreadsheets
Tab 1: "Cats"

```
Type    Color   size   weight
Calico  white   20     25
Tuxedo  black   15     16
Dumb    orange  12     22
```

Tab 2: "Dogs"

```
Type        Color   size   weight
St Bernard  cerulea 125    200
Beagle      pink    25     30
Adorable    blue    45     50
```

I'd want to have the "type" in the drop down menu and let's say St. Bernard is selected.
I want a label or cells to be populated with that type's color, size, and weight.

It's essentially a search function.  Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Filters? Select the table then Click the Data Tab then click on filter (Ctrl + L).

Comment: I don't want to use a filter.  I need this to be done within a form with a one click button.  You click the button and it populates the attributes from the "dog" that has been selected in the drop down menu.

Comment: Just a GUI using VLookup sounds like what you are after

Comment: Can you point me to any forums on this, or help stir me in the right direction?  You've already helped, but like I said, this is pretty new to me.

Comment: If you don't currently know how to use the VLookup excel function then that is your first step, this can be called in vba with `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(...)` You then need to design a GUI, there are many tutorials for that, you can asign a button to the Sub so that you click a button in the worksheet and the GUI pops up. You could use MsgBox to display the result